# Reusing Memory Streams

Tags: c#

Assume I have copied a byte buffer into a memory stream using this

```
memoryStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Is there any way for me to empty the stream and reuse it to read additional data?

I want to avoid creating many MemoryStream objects and prefer to use one instance, resetting it between usages

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the `Position` to 0, this will in effect reset the stream.

However, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629666/want-to-re-use-memorystream/4629728#4629728) answer indicates, reusing memory streams will not likely gain you any performance benefits. It is cheaper to create more memory streams.

Another option it to use a pinned `byte[]` as your buffer for reuse.

Comment: Sure - But if the stream already contains 100 bytes and I write 99 bytes then when I come to read the contents of this stream I will read too much :)

Comment: @CycleMachine - there is a reason why resetting/clearing memory streams is not built in. See the linked answer I have added.

Comment: If you allocate a large buffer it would be more efficient to reuse the buffer vs reallocating everytime. Rather than setting the position you can use SetLength(0) (see my answer below) which will keep the buffer allocated and reset the internal counters, length and position, which is cheaper than reallocating a large buffer frequently.

Comment: The correct answer is below, SetLength(0). This answer is incorrect.

Comment: This answer is WRONG!  WRONG! WRONG! WRONG! and should be deleted.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `Position` just sets the read/write position, but keeps the length of the data in the stream. So subsequent reads once again give you the data already written to the stream. Use `SetLength(0)` to reset both. The linked answer is also wrong. SetLength(0) does reset the length and position and **does keep** the buffer.

Comment: @WarlikeChimpanzee: Instead of yelling it would be more in the spirit of SO to give a reason for your comment ;-)

Answer (score 51):

You can re-use the MemoryStream by Setting the Position to 0 and the Length to 0.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

// Do some stuff with the stream

// Reset the stream so you can re-use it
ms.Position = 0; // Not actually needed, SetLength(0) will reset the Position anyway
ms.SetLength(0);

// Do some more stuff with the stream
```

By setting the length to 0 you do not clear the existing buffer, it only resets the internal counters. So the existing buffer allocation remains intact, but all the book keeping of how much of the buffer is used is reset so that you can re-use it.

**Update:** I just took a quick look at the code implementation for SetLength and if you set the length to 0 the Position will automatically be reset to 0 so you do not even need to explicitly set the Position property it is enough to just reset the length.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use `memoryStream.getBuffer()` and offsets/length(use `memoryStream.Position` and `memoryStream.Length` for detecting boundaries) for directly accessing `byte[]` data, `Reader`/`Writer`/`BinaryFormatter` classes, or other classes accepting `Stream`, for reading/writing primitive/complex types into buffer(that's what `MemoryStream` is made for), you manage without useless copying operations, because `MemoryStream` is already based on byte-array.

I used it this way with asynchronous send/receive socket operations accepting `byte[]`, But beware - if you wrote something into buffer beyond its current `Length` and want to increase its length with `SetLength()` for reading with Reader class - you get very inconvenient behavior(in my opinion) - this method nullify every byte between old length and new length if the length increases.

I solved this problem by modifying source code(one Array.Clear call in `SetLength()`, and some additions to manage without internal classes of .NET)  of `MemoryStream` and using it in my project.

As for reusing MemoryStream, i agree with Chris Taylor's answer(`SetLength(0)`)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer suggests that

> reusing memory streams will not likely gain you any performance benefits

Wrong. **It will**.

Benchmark for .NET 8:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Reuse | 6.742 ns | 0.7124 ns | 0.0390 ns | - | - |
| Recreate | 15.762 ns | 0.8838 ns | 0.0484 ns | 0.0069 | 344 B |

The benchmark recreates (vs. resets and reuses) the memory stream and writes a byte array into it.

So use the most upvoted answer by @Chris:

```
ms.SetLength(0);
```

Answer (score -3):

memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);